# What would happen if we test the Hagen-Poiseuille law with a superfluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, superfluidity

When we have a laminar flow we can test the [Hagen-Poiseuille law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation) from the pressure difference created by the flow of the fluid. This process is created due to conservation of total energy but the liquid rises due to capillary action which is due to viscosity. Now if I have a superfluid which has zero viscosity and I successfully create a pressure difference by lowering the pipe as usual then would we see capillary action? So would we see that there is no difference between the superfluid levels in two points although the liquid flows? Please explain what will happen.